# Position fixed on the left doesn't work with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a 100vh html page with a horizontal scroll. I have need to fixed a div on the left, but it doesn't work with position: fixed.

This is my example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="scroll">
      <div class="fixed">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    .container {
        width: 1000px;
        transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
        transform-origin: top left;
        background-color: grey;
        .scroll {
          height: 300px;
          .fixed {
            position: fixed;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100%;
            background: red
          }
        }
    }
}
```

If you try to mouse wheel inside the div, the fixed div not working.

Thank you!

Comment: That's not CSS. CSS doesn't do nesting.

Comment: I'm not even sure why people use SCSS... just seems like code to write code that is just as easy to write with plain CSS. That being said, your issue is not the fixed position. You don't have a width on your `.wrapper`, then you rotate, so it's only the height of the whatever you put in that `.fixed` div.

Answer (score 0):

You are using parentheses incorrectly. You should open { then type the code and then close it}

This is how to write your own code.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
    transform-origin: top left;
    background-color: grey;
}
.scroll {
    height: 300px;
}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red
}
```